# Do multiple vcpu help if you are using nodejs without multithread?

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine, vcpu

I am using google cloud compute engine and it recommends using their 2vcpu machine type. However I'm only using nodejs and it is a single thread application. WIll it make a difference